# Shift + up arrow behaviour on number field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement in which I need jump of 10 on pressing Shift+up/down arrow key on html number field, anyone knows if there's any existing solution or any way to do that?

Any kind of suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean, having a number field which should get incremented by 10 when the user tends to press Shift+Up arrow?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED] You can achieve that using below snippet,

**Checkout this JSFiddle demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ctkt66a0/9/

**HTML:**

```
<label for="user_lic">Number of user license : </label><input id="user_lic" type="text" value ="5" />
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38)
    {
        if (e.shiftKey === true)
        {
            // new line
            //alert('yes');
                        var valu = parseInt($('#user_lic' ).val()) + parseInt(10);
            //alert(valu);
            $('#user_lic').val('');
            $('#user_lic').val('').val(valu);
        }
        else
        {
            // run your function
        }
        return false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        if (e.shiftKey === true)
        {
            // new line
            //alert('yes');
                        var valu = parseInt($('#user_lic' ).val()) - parseInt(10);
            //alert(valu);
            $('#user_lic').val('');
            $('#user_lic').val('').val(valu);
        }
        else
        {
            // run your function
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: I need this jump only when user presses up arrow key with shift, else there will be increment or decrement of 1 on single key press of up/down arrow keys..

Comment: Want to have same behaviour as adobe photoshop have, Increase/decrease selected values by 10 on Shift + Up Arrow/Down Arrow

Comment: this is somehow 50% correct, also need to check on clicking up/down arrow by pressing shift key, we have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are a bit odd, and this is a question I often find myself wondering (it should be built in, surely!).

This code loops through every number input. If you haven't pressed shift or pressed up or down it bails early, and if the input has a blank value it gives it a value of 0 first (because you can't add or subtract from an empty string). It is a wrapped in a self invoking function so I could include the `UP` and `DOWN` consts.

```
(function(){
  const UP = 38;
  const DOWN = 40;
  Array
    .from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=\"number\"]"))
    .forEach( input => {
      input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if(!e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode != UP && e.keyCode != DOWN)){
          return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        if(input.value == ""){
          input.value = 0;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == UP){
          return input.value = parseFloat(input.value) + 10;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == DOWN){
          input.value = parseFloat(input.value) - 10;
        }
      });
    })  
})();
```

And an example:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/bfde2271e0bf3eeaab347b4eeac06efe?editors=0010

Answer (score -1):

check this [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snf1q5o5/)

you can use the `step` attribute